# No output for JSoup file

Tags: java, web-scraping, error-handling, jsoup

When running the following code:

```
  try {
     Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://pomofocus.io/").get();
     Elements text = doc.select("div.sc-kEYyzF");
     System.out.println(text.text());
  } 
  catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

No output occurs. When changing the `println` to:

```java
System.out.println(text.first().text());
```

I get a `NullPointerException` but nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

jsoup doesn't execute javascript - it parses the HTML that the server returns. You can check View Source (vs Inspect) to see the response from the server, and what is selectable.

Comment: It was a div element I selected and I'm trying to get my program to output the text that was in the div. Would it be helpful to include the line of HTML that I'm trying to get at? Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Sure, adding detail couldn't hurt. Perhaps there's another easy way to get the content you're after, vs running a scraper that executes Javascript.

Comment: <div class="sc-kEYyzF gkSMJF">Login</div>

Comment: The line of html I'm trying to get at.

Comment: Yes, that div is created by Javascript executing in the browser on document load. Jsoup doesn't execute Javascript; the DOM it gets is a result only of parsing the server's response HTML. You can see the returned HTML by looking at View Source, not Inspect, in your browser.